# Xamarin Android - Wifisuggestions does not suggest any wifi

Tags: android, xamarin, android-10.0

Hi all I'm using the new wifisuggestionsstory and I have implemented this in Xamarin but I don't get any suggestions..., I have no network setup and there is no wifi connection on my android device. It should once I come in range connect with the wifi router that is defined but it doesn't suggest it nor connect to it. However when I view my possible wifi connections the router is present but it doesn't suggest it... I use the following example code (the status is btw succesfull so it adds the suggestions):

```
var guestUsers = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
    .SetSsid("GuestNetwork")
    .SetWpa2Passphrase("hunter2")
    .Build();

var secretEnterpriseNetwork = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
    .SetSsid("Cyberdyne")
    .SetWpa2Passphrase(":D/-<")
    .Build();

var suggestions = new[] { guestUsers, secretEnterpriseNetwork };

var wifiManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService) as WifiManager;
var status = wifiManager.AddNetworkSuggestions(suggestions);

if (status == NetworkStatus.SuggestionsSuccess)
{
    // We added suggestions!
}
```

Anybody a clue why android Q does not suggest to connect to the wifi router defined in the code? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to this question, if you manually disconnect from that network, you can't reconnect to this wifi point by code. Because it is blacklisted for 24 hours...

This is what the documentation says about it:

> If the user uses the Wi-Fi picker to explicitly disconnect from one of
>   the network suggestions when connected to it, then that network is
>   blacklisted for 24 hours. During the blacklist period, that network
>   will not be considered for auto-connection, even if the app removes
>   and re-adds the network suggestion corresponding to the network.

Man what a **pain**

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.